# Hover over parent element shows href of child a element

Tags: javascript

I've created a list item element that contains a child anchor element.

```
<ul id="machine-list">
    <li>
        <a href="gosomewhere">Somewhere</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Using jQuery I'm binding a `click` event to the list item. When the user clicks I'm grabbing the first anchor tag's href attribute and moving the user to that page.

While this works nicely I'd like to simulate the same hover effect that hovering over a link usually has: showing the referenced link in the status bar. Unfortunately `window.status` is not getting it done.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#machine-list > li')
    .css('cursor', 'pointer')
    .click(
        function (e) {
            window.location = $(e.target).find('a').attr('href');
        })
    .mouseover(
        function (e) {
            window.status = $(e.target).find('a').attr('href');
        });
});
```

What should the function in `.mouseover` look like to get the desired effect? The above code is down and dirty so any general feedback would also be appreciated.

Comment: Be aware that a lot of browsers will block access to update the status bar, specifically for the purpose of avoiding URL spoofing

Comment: @Gareth Didn't even think of that and I understand why they would do that. The `.mouseover` is definitely firing so my guess is that Chrome / Firefox are blocking the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons, `window.status` is [disabled by default](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_status.asp) in all of the major browsers. I know the link is to W3Schools, but it clearly illustrates the point. The only way you can affect the status bar is by making the user hover over a link whose URL you control.

Comment: So if I'm linking to another page internal to my site don't I "control" it? Or am I missing understanding that last part of your answer?

Comment: @ahsteele: By "control", I mean that you can change the URL of a link from either HTML or JavaScript. The link doesn't have to point to a page on your server.

Comment: meaning that a user must be hovering over an anchor element for the status bar to show a url?

Comment: @ahsteele: Yes, either that or having tabbed over to the link using the keyboard.

Comment: too bad that the bad guys screw up usability for the rest of us. I hadn't even considered the security angle when I asked the question. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just put your content within the  tag?

```
<li><a>content goes here</a></li>
```

That way it will always have the URL for any of the content within. The following is still valid syntax.

```
<li>
 <a>
  <div>
   <table>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
   </table>
  </div>
 </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the browser allow setting the status bar? You can disable that in modern browsers.